# Magento AVAILABILITY: Out of stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Created a configurable product and set Stock Availability to **in Stock** and all the associated products are in stock too.

All Qty have 10.

Categories and Website is correct as well. Status is enabled too.

Yet, it shows **AVAILABILITY: Out of stock** in the frontend. I really can't figure out where i've gone wrong!!

Some products are working though. Could someone tell me where could i have gone wrong?

All cache and index cleared

Comment: did you refresh all the cache from adminpanel ?

Comment: I have "Flush Magento Cache" and also "Flush Cache Storage" and also have re-indexed the website.

What is refresh cache?

Comment: Nobody to answer today? :(

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check - the configurable product itself can be set to in stock / out of stock.  Check it's set to 'in stock' in the inventory tab of the product edit screen.  When all child items become out of stock, it will automatically change to out of stock too if you have the manage stock settings enabled.

The other thing is you didnt mention whether you have refreshed the stock status index?  If you havent, go and do that; System > Index Management (in admin).

Tom